# Node.js download and execute external script

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I am building a simple http client using Node.js.

I wonder how to execute a JS script downloaded from a Web server (browser mimicking): 
my JS code - already tested on FF3.6 - contains both Web Workers and XMLHttpRequest Level 2.

Is Node.js capable of processing such code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will find this in the [VM module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/vm.html) which is part of the standard library. You will find [JSDOM](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to be useful as well.