# how can I upload an external js file to a server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a script for my office to take screenshots of web pages. I wish I could update my script whenever I want without having to send a new version to everyone. Is it possible to run an external JS file locally with nodejs on a server?

I'm trying to launch a js file with this code inside my computer, but it doesn't work.

```
const puppeteer = require('http://www.servername.com/app-screesnhot.js');
```

Comment: sending js to be executed on your server via an unsecured connection smells hazardous. i guess you could download it to the local server and then execute it. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235904/node-js-download-and-execute-external-script

Comment: Sounds like you want to auto-update the script (or maybe package)...maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14006439/how-to-create-a-self-updating-node-js-application) will give you some possible ideas/solutions?

Comment: Have you considered making an NPM package and including that as a dependency of other software? You could then publish new versions to NPM.

Comment: your advice seems good to me, at the moment I have created a folder locally with all the components I need to make my script work hooked via package.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Github [gist](https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/creating-gists) if this is just a small simple script, and load it via a [get](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/) request and then [evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) it.

However this sounds like a security problem, using eval to execute arbitrary code is generally bad practice.

A better way would be to publish your script as a package, but you would beed to manually update the server to use the new version.

Comment: So we would like to remove our dependency on updating an import version of a JS.  Seems like the only way to do that would be to run an arbitrary JS.  How can I find out about best practices for this?